# Updating the values in text file from an other back txt file with soft code in R

Tags: r, optimization, dataframe, text

We have this code. But this code required the manual input at each step. we can not run it for thousands or more than 10 thousands of time to get best variables values. So we need a code that will read these values from txt file that we will crear according to the given codes at the end. It reads the variable values from row-1 when i just give it a command and row-2 if i asked to read the row-2. Kindly help me.

```
dat  <-  readLines("G:/Rlearning/HYDRUS1D.txt")
replaceFn <- function(phrase, value, file){
  line <- file[grep(phrase, file)]
  value.pos <- as.numeric(gregexpr("=", line))
  file[grep(phrase, file)] <- paste0(substring(line, 1, value.pos), value)
  return(file)
}

dat <- replaceFn("WaterFlow", 3.1, dat)
dat <- replaceFn("SoluteTransport", 2.2, dat)
```

data file (HYDRUS1D.txt) that values will be updated is below

```
;
[Main]
HYDRUS_Version=4
WaterFlow=1
SoluteTransport=0
Unsatchem=0
Unsatchem=0
HP1=0
HeatTransport=0
EquilibriumAdsorption=1
MobileImmobile=0
RootWaterUptake=1
RootGrowth=0
MaterialNumbers=1
SubregionNumbers=1
SpaceUnit=cm
TimeUnit=days
PrintTimes=160
NumberOfSolutes=0
InitialCondition=1
;
[Profile]
NumberOfNodes=101
ProfileDepth=1.2E+02
ObservationNodes=5
GridVisible=1
SnapToGrid=1
ProfileWidth=80
LeftMargin=40
GridOrgX=0
GridOrgY=0
GridDX=5.E+00
GridDY=5.E+00
```

Code for writing the variables data is given below

```
W<- c(3:5)
U<-c(5:7)
H<-c(6:8)
S<-(9:11)
d <-data.frame(W, U, H, S)
write.table(d, "m.txt", row.names =FALSE, quote = FALSE, col.names = TRUE, sep = "\t")
file.show("m.txt")
```

here W is is for water flow and......
The code will read the first row values of variables and If i asked it will will read the second rows and so on. Here I just wrote 4 variables. I will write all in the original file.

Comment: or we can grep the equal sign (=) and change the values from a column made in other text file and assign them here in the sequence.

Answer (score 0):

This may work better now, based on your updated description of what needs to be done.

```
# Load required libraries
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

# Set the file paths
HD.txt.path <- file.path("G:/Rlearning/HD.txt")
HYDRUS.path <- file.path("G:/Rlearning/HYDRUS1D.txt")

# Open connection to HD.txt
fileConn <- file(HD.txt.path, open="a")

# Set values to be inserted to HD.txt
HV <- rep(4)
WF <- rep(0, 5)
ST <- rep(0, 5)
U1 <- rep(0, 5)
U2 <- rep(0, 5)
HP <- rep(0, 5)
HT <- rep(0, 5)
EA <- rep(0, 5)
MI <- rep(0, 5)
RU <- rep(0, 5)
RG <- rep(0, 5)
MN <- rep(0, 5)
SN <- rep(0, 5)
SU <- rep("cm",5)
TU <- rep("days",5)
PT <- rep(160,5)
NS <- rep(0, 5)
IC <- rep(1, 5)
NN <- rep(101, 5)
PD <- rep(1.2E+02, 5)
ON <- rep(0,5)
GV <- rep(0,5)
SG <- rep(0,5)
PW <- rep(0,5)
LM <- rep(0,5)
OX <- rep(0,5)
OY <- rep(0,5)
DX <- rep(5.E+00, 5)
DY <- rep(5.E+00, 5)

# Create dataframe of values
mydata <-data.frame(HV,WF,ST,U1,U2,HP,HT,EA,MI,RU,RG,MN,SN,SU,TU,PT,NS,IC,NN,PD,ON,GV,SG,PW,LM,OX,OY,DX,DY)

# Insert values to HD.txt
write.table(mydata, file = fileConn, row.names =FALSE, quote = FALSE, col.names = FALSE, sep = "\t")

# Close connection
close(fileConn)

# Open HD.txt
file.show(HD.txt.path)

# Read in the values from HD.txt
df.hd <- as.data.frame(readLines(HD.txt.path))

# Read the HYDRUS1D file structure and store as template
template <- as.data.frame(readLines(HYDRUS.path))

# Set column name
colnames(template) <- "Variable"

# Split dataframe into Variables and Values
template <- template %>% 
  separate(Variable,into=c("Variable","Value"),sep="=",convert=TRUE,extra="merge",fill="right")

# Create variable aliases to match with HD.txt values
Alias <- c(NA,NA,"HV","WF","ST","U1","U2","HP","HT","EA","MI","RU","RG","MN","SN","SU","TU","PT","NS","IC",NA,NA,"NN","PD","ON","GV","SG","PW","LM","OX","OY","DX","DY")

# Add aliases to the template dataframe
template <- cbind(template, Alias)

# Create the replaceFn
replaceFn <- function(phrase, value, file)
{
  # Replace the specified values
  file <- file %>%
    mutate(Value = ifelse(Alias == phrase,value,Value))

  return(file)
}

# Create a function to handle reading data, which takes a row number as input into the variable i
read.data <- function(i)
{
  # Create a new dat dataframe from the template dataframe
  dat <- template

  # Assign each value from the current row of HD.txt to the dataframe
  for(c in 1:ncol(df.hd))
  {
    dat <- replaceFn(colnames(df.hd)[c], df.hd[i,c], dat)
  }

  # Merge the data into a single output column with variables and values separated by =
  dat <- dat %>%
    mutate(Output = case_when(!is.na(.$Value) ~ paste(.$Variable,.$Value,sep = "="),
                              TRUE ~ .$Variable)) %>%
    select(Output)

  # Write values out to text file
  write.table(dat, HYDRUS.path, row.names =FALSE, na = "", quote = FALSE, col.names = FALSE)

  # Open HYDRUS file
  file.show(HYDRUS.path)

  # If not the last row of HD.txt then prompt to continue
  if(i != nrow(df.hd))
  {
    continue <- readline("Would you like to continue (y/n)?")
    if (tolower(substr(continue, 1, 1)) == "n")
    {continue <- FALSE}
    else if (tolower(substr(continue, 1, 1)) == "y")
    {
      continue <- TRUE
    }
  }

  return(continue)
}

continue <- TRUE

# Loop until continue == FALSE
while(continue == TRUE)
{
  invalid <- TRUE
  # Loop until invalid == FALSE
  while(invalid == TRUE)
  {
    # Retrieve input from user
    rownum <- readline("Enter a row number to process. (Enter 0 to loop through all rows):")

    # Convert input to numeric
    rownum <- suppressWarnings(as.numeric(rownum))
    # Make sure input is not NA, and is a valid row of df.hd
    if(!is.na(rownum) & rownum >= 0 & rownum <= nrow(df.hd))
      # Set invalid to FALSE
      {invalid <- FALSE}

    # Print error if input is invalid
    if(invalid == TRUE)
      {print(paste("Invalid input! Please enter a number from 0 through", nrow(df.hd)))}
  }

  # If user has selected 0
  if(rownum == 0)
  {
    # Loop through each row of HD.txt data
    for(i in 1:nrow(df.hd))
    {
      # Create HYDRUS1D.txt for current row
      continue <- read.data(i)
      if(continue == FALSE)
      {break}
    }
  }
  else
  {
    # Create HYDRUS1D.txt for specified row
    continue <- read.data(rownum)
  }
}
```

Comment: U did not followed my question. I want to update the values in HYDRUS.txt file. It will read the values from m.txt. It reads the row or we can made columns that it will update the HYDRUS.txt file values. @Matt Jewett

Comment: I want to update the values after equal sign (=) in HYDRUS.txt file. for that purpose I have a file (m.txt) that contains the required values. We can make the m file according our requirement. It can be thousands of rows or columns. we can make it as its values will be easily available to the HYDRUS.txt file.

Comment: It updated the HYDRUS file. BUT I have 2 question. first it is adding the = sign in front of each value for example it is assigning the equal sing after ; and [Main]= that is not required. 2nd question is how can I change the d.f that It will read the second row for each variable. Thank you very much for doing this. I will try to learn this code. I am just learner of R.

Comment: m.txt file is table. I created it with write.table

Comment: I've modified the code in the answer to fix the output issue. I'm not sure though what you mean when you say you only want to read the second row for each variable. Are you trying to make it so that it will read both the first and second row automatically, and then prompt to continue for each row afterwards?

Comment: Check the HYDRUS file. I want to improve it. I am writing a lengthy code for it.   Check my given code that I am trying. It is not completed yet. I am putting it in Answer.

Comment: I made it easier, I removed the four characters in the base file. these were ; , [Main], ; ,[Profile]. I will write it as writeLines and will place it on the correct site. Now I just want to replace the column of values with new column. I picked this part from your written algorithm. I mentioned all the step along with code. Now you can easily guide me.

Comment: I have modified my answer, and it should provide the exact output you need. Note I have added variables for the Profile section of the HD.txt file that you were missing in your example. Please also keep in mind that the way this code works will continuously overwrite the HYDRUS1D.txt file. So even if you have 5 rows in HD.txt, you will only ever output 1 HYDRUS1D.txt file in the end.

Comment: i am getting this error. function (df, dots) 
{
 .Call("dplyr_mutate_impl", PACKAGE = "dplyr", df, dots)
}

Comment: one more thing, Yes I need it will write just one row from the HD.txt file but that ow will be my choice. I will just assign the row number and it will pick the data from that row. in this code this flexibility is not available. I Put the rep() function for HD.txt file. It will be change. some will be sequence with increasing and decreasing values and some fixed with repetition.

Comment: I have updated my answer to include code that will allow you to chose to either specify a particular row, or to loop through all rows. This will be the last revision to this code that I will be providing. Please keep in mind that stackoverflow is not a resource to have someone develop entire applications for you, but rather a place to receive assistance with particular questions you may have about making your own code function properly.

Comment: I am getting this error. I run the and it shows HD.txt file and I enter row number 3. as i paste it here. Enter a row number to process. (Enter 0 to loop through all rows):3
Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  wrong result size (33), expected 29 or 1

Comment: That's because the code is only written to handle the 29 variables that were included in your original HYDRUS1D.txt file, and your hd.txt file seems to contain 33 variables. If you have additional variables to include, you will need to modify the code to handle those appropriately.

Comment: my HD file contains 29 variables. I checked now. I checked it in the above code that is creating the HD file and I also checked the HD file in the drive it has 29 variables (columns).

Answer (score 0):

I made this code, but is not excellent code. it required the row entery in the center. The code wrote by one friend here is not working. if it will work it will great. because it was just demanding the row entry at the end. I hope he will do perfectly. he is not taking observation.

```
lfz <- as.data.frame(readLines("G:/Rlearning/wrds.txt"))
```

the wrds.txt file consist of all the words and equal sing as in the required file.

```
HYDRUS_Version=
WaterFlow=
.
.
.
.
GridDX=
GridDY=

#creating input file for HYDRUS1D input file
#table of all variable after = sign
fileConn <- file("HD.txt", open="a")
HV<- rep(5, 5)
WF<-rep(0, 5)
ST<-rep(0, 5)
U1<-rep(0, 5)
U2<-rep(0, 5)
HP<-rep(0, 5)
HT<-rep(0, 5)
EA<-rep(0, 5)
MI<-rep(0, 5)
RU<-rep(0, 5)
RG<-rep(0, 5)
MN<-rep(0, 5)
SN<-rep(0, 5)
SU <-rep("cm",5)
TU<-rep("days",5)
PT<- rep(160,5)
NS <-rep(0, 5)
IC <- rep(1, 5)
NN <- rep(101, 5)
PD<- rep(1.2E+02, 5)
ON<- rep(160,5)
GV<- rep(160,5)
SG<- rep(160,5)
PW<- rep(160,5)
LM<- rep(160,5)
GX<- rep(160,5)
GY<- rep(160,5)
Gx<- rep(160,5)
Gy<- rep(160,5)
mydata <-data.frame(HV,WF,ST,U1,U2,HP,HT,EA,MI,RU,RG,MN,SN,SU,TU,PT,NS,IC,NN,PD,ON,GV,SG,PW,LM,GX,GY,Gx,Gy)
write.table(mydata, file = fileConn, row.names =FALSE, quote = FALSE, col.names = FALSE, sep = "\t")
close(fileConn)

file.show("HD.txt")
#reading the specific row of variables
Nt<- read.table("G:/Rlearning/HD.txt")
R2<-(Nt[3,])

#Change it to clumn
C1 <- as.data.frame(t(R2), col.names=FALSE, row.names=FALSE)


outVec <- gsub("\\s*", "", paste(lfz[,1], C1[,1])) 
writeLines(outVec, "outfile.txt") 

file.show("outfile.txt")

imported_text <- readLines("outfile.txt")

imported_text2 <- c(";","[Main]",imported_text)

final_text <- c(imported_text2[1:20],";","[Profile]",imported_text2[21:length(imported_text2)])

writeLines(final_text, "HYDR.txt")
file.show("HYDR.txt")
```